# Can I get specific css values using js?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I'm messing around with css `:hover` effects and try to use  `computedStyleMap().get()`  to detect css changes while hovering. It works well in chrome, but is there any **firefox** alternative that can be used?

```
function myFunction() {
actualStyle = document.querySelector('.box-1').computedStyleMap().get('cursor');
actualStyle == 'pointer' ? true:false;
}
```

trying something like a `element.addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction);`

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a browser which hasn't implemented this feature yet. It's experimental https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/computedStyleMap#browser_compatibility